# Openstack compute node Port Binding Failed

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

Creation instance failed with error:

```
Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance
```

Controller node has not any errors.
There is exception on compute node:

```
nova.exception.PortBindingFailed: Binding failed for port b70c2f30-f83c-4cae-abf8-98be39a382d5, please check neutron logs for more information.
```

Neutron's log no errors.
neutron config

```
[linux_bridge]
physical_interface_mappings = provider:ens3

[vxlan]
enable_vxlan = true
local_ip = 10.101.1.46
l2_population = true

[securitygroup]
enable_security_group = true
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.IptablesFirewallDriver
```

How can I fix port binding?

Comment: We would need more detailed logs to help you.

Answer (score 1):

- 1, check the port create successful by `openstack port show b70c2f30-f83c-4cae-abf8-98be39a382d5`, I guess it's good because of the nova execute `PortBinding`.
- 2, check whether the all network component works by `openstack network agent list`, and check the not works component's log.
- 3, make sure the all `hypervisor` are at consistent time.

Comment: 1) No Port found for <port uuid>
2) all components work
3) no idea how to check it

Comment: @NotSuperHacker try KASHIF IQBAL's method. 3), run `date` command to get the machine's time.

Comment: Fri Oct 22 15:29:26 UTC 2021 on controller | 
Fri 22 Oct 2021 03:29:33 PM UTC on compute

Comment: @NotSuperHacker try set they at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

did this port created first then try to attach as interface ? if yes pleas check port owner ( project) .
Port type you created is normal or direct ?